# What is JBPM? Why use it?

Tags: java, jboss, frameworks, redhat, jbpm

I am java developer. I am developing a new application. In this application am going to integrate JBPM, spring and hibernate also.

So please, answer my below questions,

1. what is JBPM?
2. Why use it?
3. What is workflow engine?

please give any example.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: My recommendation will be not to use it as mentioned in an answer it terrible and buggy all over

Answer (score 9):

1. JBPM is a good word for IT managers, a nightmare for programmers.
2. Do not use it. Jbpm full with bugs..
3. A workflow engine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_engine

Comment: Nice. How long have you used it?

Comment: I have been using jbpm for 2 years.

Comment: Thanks my manager too suggested. Finally, we did not have enough time for it.

Comment: @Sisak, So only we are called Developer.

Comment: This answer does little more than state your dislike for the jBPM project and provide a link to Wikipedia.

Comment: This answer does exactly what it is supposed to do... deter developers from using this terrible technology

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBPM):

> jBPM is an open-source workflow engine written in Java that can execute business processes described in BPMN 2.0 (or its own process definition language jPDL in earlier versions). It is released under the ASL (or LGPL in earlier versions) by the JBoss community.

For complete information you can check [this](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.1/userguide/) out.

Quoting from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_engine):

> A workflow engine is a software application that defines a process, the rules governing process decisions, and routes information. It is a key component in workflow technology and typically makes use of a database server.

The relationship:

jBpm is a flexible, extensible workflow management system. Business processes , expressed in a simple and powerfull language and packaged in process archives, serve as input for the jBpm runtime server. jBpm bridges the gap between managers and developers by giving them a common language : the jBpm Process definition language (jPdl).